# Getting HTTP 429 (Too Many Requests) Error with a Single API Call in React Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, chatbot

I'm building a chatbot application using React and the OpenAI API. Despite apparently making a single API call, I'm consistently receiving a (HTTP 429) error:

> "Too Many Requests".

I've checked my application for unintentional repeated requests but haven't been able to find the issue.

The error I'm encountering is as follows:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 429 ()
> Error in API call: Error: HTTP error! Status: 429

Forgive me but I'm not sure what part is wrong so I'm going to put my whole App.JSX in here.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import "@chatscope/chat-ui-kit-styles/dist/default/styles.min.css";
import {
  MainContainer,
  ChatContainer,
  MessageList,
  Message,
  MessageInput,
  TypingIndicator,
} from "@chatscope/chat-ui-kit-react";

const API_KEY = "MY_API_KEY_HERE"; //Didn't want to share my API key but this is where it is. 

const systemMessage = {
  role: "system",
  content: "Explain things simply.",
};

function App() {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([
    {
      message:
        "Text here ...",
      sentTime: "just now",
      sender: "ChatGPT",
    },
  ]);
  const [isTyping, setIsTyping] = useState(false);

  const handleSend = async (message) => {
    console.log("handleSend called with message:", message); //debugging
    const newMessage = {
      message,
      direction: "outgoing",
      sender: "user",
    };

    const newMessages = [...messages, newMessage];

    setMessages(newMessages);

    setIsTyping(true);
    await processMessageToChatGPT(newMessages);
  };

  async function processMessageToChatGPT(
    chatMessages,
    includePrewrittenMessage = false,
    prewrittenMessage = ""
  ) {
    console.log("processMessageToChatGPT called");

    // Define the apiMessages based on chatMessages and potentially a prewrittenMessage
    let apiMessages = chatMessages.map((messageObject) => {
      let role = "";
      if (messageObject.sender === "ChatGPT") {
        role = "assistant";
      } else {
        role = "user";
      }
      return { role: role, content: messageObject.message };
    });

    if (includePrewrittenMessage) {
      apiMessages.push({
        role: "user",
        content: prewrittenMessage,
      });
    }

    // Define apiRequestBody here
    const apiRequestBody = {
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      messages: [systemMessage, ...apiMessages],
    };

    // Now make the API call
    await fetch("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + API_KEY,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(apiRequestBody),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setMessages([
          ...chatMessages,
          {
            message: data.choices[0].message.content,
            sender: "ChatGPT",
          },
        ]);
        setIsTyping(false);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error in API call:", error);
        setIsTyping(false);
        // Handle the error state in your UI
      });
  }



  const quickStartButton = async () => {
    const prewrittenMessage =
      "Message here...";

    setIsTyping(true);
    await processMessageToChatGPT(messages, true, prewrittenMessage);
  };

  const randoChar = async () => {
    const prewrittenMessage =
      "Message here...";

    setIsTyping(true);
    await processMessageToChatGPT(messages, true, prewrittenMessage);
  };

  const createCampaign = async () => {
    const prewrittenMessage =
      "Message here...";

    setIsTyping(true);
    await processMessageToChatGPT(messages, true, prewrittenMessage);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Welcome to the realm of DnDAI,</h1>
      <h2>
        Where you are only bound to the magic of your mind... or my coding.
      </h2>
      <h4>Adventure Awaits...</h4>
      <button onClick={quickStartButton}>Quick Start</button>
      <button onClick={randoChar}>Create a random character</button>
      <button onClick={createCampaign}>Create a campaign</button>
      <div style={{ position: "relative", height: "600px", width: "1200px" }}>
        <MainContainer>
          <ChatContainer>
            <MessageList
              scrollBehavior="smooth"
              typingIndicator={
                isTyping ? (
                  <TypingIndicator content="Generating world..." />
                ) : null
              }
            >
              {messages.map((message, i) => {
                console.log(message);
                return <Message key={i} model={message} />;
              })}
            </MessageList>
            <MessageInput placeholder="Type message here" onSend={handleSend} />
          </ChatContainer>
        </MainContainer>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. Checking for repeated state updates or re-renders that might cause multiple API calls.
2. Using the Network tab in the browser's developer tools to monitor requests.
3. Ensuring there are no infinite loops or recursive calls in my code.
4. Inspecting the component lifecycle for any unintended API calls.

I'm puzzled as to why this error appears with just one message being sent. Is there something I'm overlooking in my React setup or API call process? Any thoughts or suggestions for further debugging would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you read the [error definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429)? The API you're calling has a rate-limiting policy, which means you are aloud to make at most an N number of requests over a T period of time, and you have exceeded N within less than T. I have no idea what N and T are in your case but, in general, a rate-limited API displays its limits prominently, along with a call to action inviting you to pay a fee to remove the limit. The rate limit is not calculated per app instance.

Comment: [OpenAI API - Rate limits](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/rate-limits). You're limited to 200 requests per day and 20k per month.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards the rate limits. I've confirmed that the gpt-3.5-turbo model allows 3 requests per minute and 200 per day. My app is well under these limits, making only one request at a time, but I'm still encounter a 429 error on the first try after idle time. I'm not sure why it seems not to exceed the RPM or RPD. Any idea why this might happen or how to address it?

Comment: *making only one request at a time* - at one request at a time, 3 requests per minute (i.e. one every 20 seconds) you can reach the daily limit in about an hour ... so, making one request at a time is no indication that you haven't hit the limit today